# How can i change/add a breakpoint in Foundation 6?

Tags: zurb-foundation, breakpoints, breakpoint-sass

i started a new project using Foundation 6 and there is one problem i can't fix.
My Topbar has a lot of links and when it comes to <= 800px the topbar breaks into two columns, so that it doesn't look good anymore.
Now i want to add a new breakpoint and set the data-hide-for value to this new breakpoint.

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="test">
<button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="responsive-menu"></button>
```

But when i change for test purpose the medium breakpoint from 640px to 800px in the _settings.scss, the topbar still breaks at 640px, like i haven't change anything.

```
$breakpoints: (small: 0,medium: 640px,test: 800px,large: 1024px,xlarge: 1200px,xxlarge: 1440px,);
```

Does anybody have a solution for my problem ?

Comment: You've done the right thing on the breakpoint side in the scss (just tested it locally), so my suspicion is there's something else going on that is interfering. Can you post the html you're using for the topbar itself, not just the responsive toggle piece of it?